# Async problems whith Array.filter

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, typescript, array-filter

I'm using `Ionic2 / Angular2` with `typescript` and I have a problem while filtering an Array.

I have

```
let localTours = [];
...
let newTours = dbTours.filter(x => localTours.indexOf(x) < 0);
localTours.push(newTours);
```

In this example my `localTours` is always empty, because the `.push` is called before the filtering. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: filter is not the problem, `something()` might be. Please show that function. Nothing in the code you are showing is async

Comment: Actually the code looks like this: `let newTours = dbTours.filter(x => localTours.indexOf(x) < 0);` and then `localTours.push(newTours);`. I will update the code in the question.

Comment: Update your code to include where `localTours` is coming from.

Comment: What about dbTours? Is that an array, or a db object? Something like an ORM? And the filter method is actually going against the db?

Comment: It's an array I get of the subscription of a `Observable<Tour[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Either your filtering is wrong and is filtering EVERYTHING thus giving you an empty array as a result, OR your something function is async, in which case you would benefit from using something like the [async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library and so something like:

```
oneArray.filter(something, (err, results) => {
   otherArray.push(results);
});
```

And your something function, looks like:

```
function something(item, callback) {
  //your filtering logic needs to call the callback function to move onto the next item
}
```